# Form of $D^{\frac{1}{k}}$ of a diagonal matrix $D$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix i.e., $D=\operatorname{diag}(d_1, \cdots, d_n)$. Then is there any formula or process of computing $D^{\frac{1}{k}}$?

I know one solution, i.e., $D^{\frac{1}{k}}= \operatorname{diag}(d_1^{\frac{1}{k}}, \cdots, d_n^{\frac{1}{k}})$ but after consideration of $I_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0  \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$, I see $D^{\frac{1}{k}}$ might contain non-diagonal matrix, so I wonder is there any formula or systematic way to computing them.

For $I_2 = I_2 \cdot I_2$ and $I_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: The real important question here is: what do you mean by the symbol $D^{1/k}$? As your example shows, for a diagonal matrix $D$, it can be there more than one matrix $E$ such that $E^k = D$.

Comment: @azifoo I mean $D^{\frac{1}{k}}$ is the matrix whose $k$ product gives $D$. For your notation $E$, which satisfies $E^k=D$ is my $D^{\frac{1}{k}}$.